# how to push each occurence of a class into separate array

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

i have i situation like this,

i have one `class` called `checkbox-group`  having 2 `occurences` like this

```
<div class="check-group">
    <input type="checkbox" value="abc" checked="checked"/>
    <label>abc</label>

     <input type="checkbox" value="xyz"/>
    <label>xyz</label>
</div>
```

**IN** the same `document` i have one more occurence of `check-group` `class`

like this,

```
<div class="check-group">
    <input type="checkbox" value="pqrs" checked="checked"/>
    <label>pqrs</label>
</div>
```

**now my question** is how can i make different `array` on each occurence of `check-group` `class`  ?   like this  `array1 = ["abc"]; AND array2 = ["pqrs"]`

the problem is i may not be knowing the number of occurence of `check-group` `class`   as im using `dynamic` `form builder`.

NOTE: Please let `array` to `grow` as `per` the `class` occurence.

**here is demo** :  https://jsfiddle.net/gfux198s/27/   (no two `array` the `array` does not grow as per the occurence of `class`)

thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this: https://jsfiddle.net/gfux198s/28/?

Comment: what do you mean by _Please let array to grow as per the class occurence_?

Comment: there are 2 times `check-group` class appears so `i need 2 array` having its own `checked value`.  if `check-group` class appears 3 times `then 3 array i need having its own value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function create_checkgroup_arrays(){
  var checkgroupArray = [];  
  var i=0;
  $(".check-group").each(function(){
    checkgroupArray[i] = [];
    $(this).find("input:checkbox:checked").each(function(){
      checkgroupArray[i].push($(this).val());
    });    
    i++;
  });
  console.log(checkgroupArray);
}
$("#_click_it").on("click",function(){
  create_checkgroup_arrays()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="check-group">
  <input type="checkbox" value="abc" checked="checked"/>
  <label>abc</label>

  <input type="checkbox" value="xyz"/>
  <label>xyz</label>
</div>

<div class="check-group">
  <input type="checkbox" value="pqrs" checked="checked"/>
  <label>pqrs</label>
</div>
<input type="button" id="_click_it" value="click_it">
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of all `check-group` elements:

```
const groups = document.getElementsByClassName('check-group');
```

To get a list of lists of checkbox values within each group:

```
const valueGroups = Array.from(groups).map((group) => {
    const checkboxes = group.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
    return Array.from(checkboxes).map((elem) => {
        return elem.value;
    });
});
```

If elements are being dynamically inserted into the document (i.e. using an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)), then collecting these values should happen there instead of querying the document like this.

One nifty feature you might be able to make use of is the fact that [getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a live list of elements. It will update automatically in response to the DOM. However it won't rerun these map functions for you or anything like that.

A last resort technique for reacting to changes that you don't control is using a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to react directly to changes in the DOM. But beware, this is time expensive.

Comment: any `example` would `help me` thanks for the `answer`

Comment: @user5405873 I added some example code. I hope you find it useful.